# Error uploading image to s3 using laravel filament

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I am trying to upload an image file to digital ocean space using an s3 driver from a Laravel Filament project. The image is successfully uploaded to the space bucket in the default temporary folder of Livewire. But when I save the form, it gives me an error saying

> Unable to check existence for: livewire-tmp/imagepath.jpg

I tried using different env combinations and it only worked for the public disk.

This is my current code for the resource file:

```
public static function form(Form $form): Form
{
    return $form
        ->schema([
            Forms\Components\Section::make('Content')
                ->schema([
                    TextInput::make('title')
                        ->label('Title')
                        ->required()
                        ->live(onBlur: true)->maxLength(255)
                        ->afterStateUpdated(fn(string $operation, $state, Forms\Set $set) => $operation === 'create' ? $set('slug', Str::slug($state)) : null),
                    TextInput::make('slug')
                        ->label('Slug')
                        ->disabled()
                        ->dehydrated()
                        ->required()
                        ->maxLength(255)
                        ->unique(Post::class, 'slug', ignoreRecord: true),
                    Textarea::make('description')
                        ->label('Description')
                        ->columnSpan('full'),
                    Forms\Components\MarkdownEditor::make('content')
                        ->label('Content')
                        ->required()
                        ->columnSpan('full'),
                    Select::make('category_id')
                        ->label('Category')
                        ->preload()
                        ->relationship('category', 'name')
                        ->searchable()
                        ->columnSpan('full')
                        ->required()
                        ->createOptionForm([
                            TextInput::make('name')
                                ->label('Name')
                                ->required()
                                ->unique(Category::class, 'name', ignoreRecord: true)
                                ->live(onBlur: true)->maxLength(255),

                        ]),
                ])->columns(),
            Section::make('Image')->relationship('image')->schema([  #this is the place
                FileUpload::make('path')
                    ->directory('posts')
                    ->disk('s3')
                    ->visibility('private')
            ])
        ]);
}
```

Livewire config value:

```
'temporary_file_upload' => [
    'disk' => 's3',        // Example: 'local', 's3'              | Default: 'default'
    'rules' => null,       // Example: ['file', 'mimes:png,jpg']  | Default: ['required', 'file', 'max:12288'] (12MB)
    'directory' => null,   // Example: 'tmp'                      | Default: 'livewire-tmp'
    'middleware' => null,  // Example: 'throttle:5,1'             | Default: 'throttle:60,1'
    'preview_mimes' => [   // Supported file types for temporary pre-signed file URLs...
        'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg', 'wav', 'mp4',
        'mov', 'avi', 'wmv', 'mp3', 'm4a',
        'jpg', 'jpeg', 'mpga', 'webp', 'wma',
    ],
    'max_upload_time' => 5, // Max duration (in minutes) before an upload is invalidated...
],
```

.env values

```
FILESYSTEM_DISK=s3
FILAMENT_FILESYSTEM_DISK=s3
```

Image Model file:

```
class Image extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

public function post(): BelongsTo
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a repo reproducing this error

Comment: If possible pls share the error via flareapp

Comment: The `temporary_file_upload` config decides the location of the file before you actually make it permanent. Most often you want to store this locally, and only *after* this would you store it to S3. That last setting defined using the `disk()` (which points to `config/filesystems.php`) on your `FileUpload` element. However your case should somehow work too but I can't tell from the amount of info you gave.

Comment: https://github.com/yeasirhridoy/blog-filament
@ManojKiran here is the repository link. You can check.